# Find average user engagement duration from API

Tags: google-analytics-api

So i though that to get the average user engagement duration, we had to get the following metrics:

- userEngagementDuration
- totalUsers

And then do: userEngagementDuration / totalUsers

However, i can't get to the same result as the UI. Couple of examples:

Page #1
API: 1 min 19 s
UI: 1 min 33 s

Page #2
API: 0 min 55 s
UI: 0 min 17 s

Page #3
API: 0 min 42 s
UI: 0 min 15 s

Sometimes the API is higher, sometimes the UI is higher.

Is it that i don't use the right metrics ?

I confirm that my date range is the exact same.

Thanks !

I tried activeUsers, sessions, etc. None gives the same result as the UI.

Comment: Hi, [this page](https://measureschool.com/ga4-metrics/) says that the GA4 average engagement time is calculated as a sum of user engagement durations per **active user**. So I would definitely suggest dividing by activeUsers not totalUsers. But you say you have tried that so I don't know what to suggest!